# How to save Coverage configurations to right click menu in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, code-coverage

I'm developing JUnit tests for one of my college courses and am having an issue where my coverage configurations are not showing up in the Coverage As submenu of the right-click menu in Eclipse. All of the video tutorials I've watched about coverage have their configurations showing up under this submenu without issue so I am unsure if the issue is with my installation of Eclipse or if I am not doing something correctly to have it appear there. I am forced to click the coverage configurations... option which brings up the configurations menu where I can then select my configuration to run coverage with.

My Eclipse version info is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
Build id: 20210910-1417
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 15.0.2+7-27
Java version: 15.0.2

Comment: Whether anything is in the _Coverage As_ right-click menu depends on where the right-click was done. So please show a screenshot that shows where you done the right-click and also that the class has a valid main method or is a JUnit test and is included in the source folder of a Java project that does not have build errors.

Comment: It does not seem to matter where I right-click within the IDE
[Screenshot of JUnit Test class](https://prnt.sc/26l6w36)
[Screenshot of Configuration window](https://prnt.sc/26l6wk2)
  
[Right click in code/open file](https://prnt.sc/26l6tr4)
[Right click on JUnit test class](https://prnt.sc/26l6u4a)
[Right click on the class being tested](https://prnt.sc/26l6vjf)

The configuration doesn't even show up in the toolbar sub menu despite being in the configuration window. [Screenshot of toolbar submenu](https://prnt.sc/26l6xjq)

Comment: The theme you have installed tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Try with the current Eclipse (2021-09 is one release behind) without additional plugins and with a fresh workspace (deactivating or disabling of the theme might not be enough). If the issue persists, please show screenshots only of a built-in theme.

Comment: I uninstalled the theme, updated Eclipse to the latest version, and created a new workspace and the issue was fixed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by my installed theme and fixed by following the instructions provided in a comment left by Howlger to my initial post.

> The theme you have installed tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Try with the current Eclipse (2021-09 is one release behind) without additional plugins and with a fresh workspace (deactivating or disabling of the theme might not be enough). If the issue persists, please show screenshots only of a built-in theme. –
> howlger